# Using database schema name from Ant properties in groovy sql

Tags: sql, groovy, ant

I am trying to execute a groovy sql select as below in Ant

```
<target name="groovy_sql">
    <groovy>
        import groovy.sql.Sql
        def sql = Sql.newInstance(properties."master.jdbc_connection_string", properties."master.database_user", properties."master.database_password", "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver")
        def table = '['+properties."app.database_name"+']..FILE_DATA'
        def row = sql.firstRow("SELECT top 1 id from ${table} order by id desc")
        properties."fileDataId" = row[0]
    </groovy>
    <echo message="fileDataId: ${fileDataId}"/>
</target>
```

And am getting below error

```
 [groovy] Sep 04, 2015 2:16:14 PM groovy.sql.Sql$AbstractQueryCommand execute
 [groovy] WARNING: Failed to execute: SELECT top 1 id from ? order by id desc because: Must declare the table variable "@P0".
```

I figured cause of this error is table name cannot be passed as parameter.
Since this script has to be run in different environments we have different schemas in different environments so I cannot hardcode the schema name and I am having hardtime figuring out the solution for this. Could someone help me with this issue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string assignment. First read from project, then concatenate.

Here is an example taking property from command line

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="demo" basedir="." default="demo">

<taskdef name="groovy"
classpath="${user.home}/.gvm/groovy/2.3.6/embeddable/groovy-all-2.3.6.jar"
classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" />

    <target name="demo">
        <!-- can load all props from a file here-->
        <property name="table" value="hardcoded"/>
        <groovy>
            <arg value="hello1"/>
             <arg value="hello2"/>
             <arg value="hello3"/>

             println  args[0]
             println  args[2]
             println 'projectName:'+ project.name
             println project.getProperty("table")

             def var="SELECT top 1 id from " + project.properties["table"] + "  order by id desc"
             println var;

        </groovy>

    </target>


</project>
```

I do not have sql environment to test it, so iit just printing.

Following shows output from a run

> $ ant

```
demo:                                                                                
   [groovy] hello1                                                                   
   [groovy] hello3                                                                   
   [groovy] projectName:demo                                                         
   [groovy] hardcoded                                                                
   [groovy] SELECT top 1 id from hardcoded  order by id desc
```

Taking command line args

```
$ ant -Dtable=newtable


demo:                                                                                
   [groovy] hello1                                                                   
   [groovy] hello3                                                                   
   [groovy] projectName:demo                                                         
   [groovy] newtable                                                                 
   [groovy] SELECT top 1 id from newtable  order by id desc
```